# How to use editMessageText with the Telegraf framework?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegraf

I have to edit a message when an inline button is pressed.
Here is my code:

```js
bot.action("option2", (ctx) => {
  ctx.answerCbQuery();

  bot.telegram.editMessageText(
    ctx.update.callback_query.message.chat.id,
    ctx.update.callback_query.message.message_id,
    `Hello`
  );
});
```

---

I'm getting the error:

```
{
  response: {
    ok: false,
    error_code: 400,
    description: 'Bad Request: message text is empty'  
  },
  on: {
    method: 'editMessageText',
    payload: {
      text: undefined,
      chat_id: 'Hello',
      message_id: { chat_id: -684957676, message_id: 578 },
      inline_message_id: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the [Telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/) framework

I believe that I don't understand the order in which I should pass arguments.

**How do I use the editMessageText?**

Answer (score 2):

You can just:

```
await ctx.editMessageText(`Hello`);
```

It will automatically find the last message in chat and change it to 'Hello'